# Flutter - What is the best way to update UI before long running process

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a long running search process and I am trying to display a CircularProgressIndicator wrapped in Visibility. The visible property is set via a ViewModel flag.

```
Visibility(
   visible: viewModel.inProgress,
   child:...
)
```

before I run the search(long running process) I update inPrgress to true and call nofityListeners() then run the search. Problem is the UI never gets updated.

```
onSearch(){
    inProgress=true;
    notifyListeners();
    search();//takes a while t complete
    inProgress=false;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

if I introduce a little delay the progress shows but runs pretty choppy.

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100),()=>_search())//a little delay to show progress
  .then((result) {
   .
   .
   .
});
```

Wondering what is the best way to accomplish this in Flutter apps.

Comment: Could you share a bit more code so I can better understand how your project is structured? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to make the `onSearch()` method async.

Comment: Thanks Mickael, please see my reply to Phuc below. Making the method Future <ResultModel> search () async {} does not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the search() function completed by putting await before search(), and of course make onSearch() async. Something like below:

```
onSearch() async {
    inProgress=true;
    notifyListeners();
    await search();//takes a while t complete
    inProgress=false;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: I did try that: Future <ResultModel> search () async {} but it did not make any difference. The problem is the code inside search is synchronous it just iterates through a long collection to find matches. I would have to move the Future.delayed to the search method which would give me the same result. The only way to make it "really" async is to execute on a separate thread and I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you share your search() method?